# MVC multi page form losing session

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, forms, session, tempdata

I have a multi-page form that's used to collect leads. There are multiple versions of the same form that we call campaigns. Some campaigns are 3 page forms, others are 2 pages, some are 1 page. They all share the same lead model and campaign controller, etc. There is 1 action for controlling the flow of the campaigns, and a separate action for submitting all the lead information into the database.

I cannot reproduce this locally, and there are checks in place to ensure users can't skip pages. Session mode is InProc.

This runs after every POST action which stores the values in session:

```
    protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);

        if (this.Request.RequestType == System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Http.Post && this._Lead != null)
            ParentStore.Lead = this._Lead;
    }
```

This is the Lead property within the controller:

```
    private Lead _Lead;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the session stored Lead model.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The Lead model stored in session.</value>
    protected Lead Lead
    {
        get
        {
            if (this._Lead == null)
                this._Lead = ParentStore.Lead;

            return this._Lead;
        }
    }
```

ParentStore class:

```
public static class ParentStore
{
    internal static Lead Lead
    {
        get { return SessionStore.Get<Lead>(Constants.Session.Lead, new Lead()); }
        set { SessionStore.Set(Constants.Session.Lead, value); }
    }
```

Campaign POST action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public virtual ActionResult Campaign(Lead lead, string campaign, int page)
    {
        if (this.Session.IsNewSession)
            return RedirectToAction("Campaign", new { campaign = campaign, page = 0 });

        if (ModelState.IsValid == false)
            return View(GetCampaignView(campaign, page), this.Lead);

        TrackLead(this.Lead, campaign, page, LeadType.Shared);

        return RedirectToAction("Campaign", new { campaign = campaign, page = ++page });
    }
```

The problem is occuring between the above action, and before the following Submit action executes:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public virtual ActionResult Submit(Lead lead, string campaign, int page)
    {
        if (this.Session.IsNewSession || this.Lead.Submitted || !this.LeadExists)
            return RedirectToAction("Campaign", new { campaign = campaign, page = 0 });

        lead.AddCustomQuestions();
        MergeLead(campaign, lead, this.AdditionalQuestionsType, false);

        if (ModelState.IsValid == false)
            return View(GetCampaignView(campaign, page), this.Lead);

        var sharedLead = this.Lead.ToSharedLead(Request.Form.ToQueryString(false)); //Error occurs here and sends me an email with whatever values are in the form collection.
        EAUtility.ProcessLeadProxy.SubmitSharedLead(sharedLead);
        this.Lead.Submitted = true;
        VisitorTracker.DisplayConfirmationPixel = true;

        TrackLead(this.Lead, campaign, page, LeadType.Shared);

        return RedirectToAction(this.ConfirmationView);
    }
```

Every visitor to our site gets a unique GUID visitorID. But when these error occurs there is a different visitorID between the Campaign POST and the Submit POST. Because we track each form submission via the TrackLead() method during campaign and submit actions I can see session is being lost between calls, despite the OnActionExecuted firing after every POST and storing the form in session.

So when there are errors, we get half the form under one visitorID and the remainder of the form under a different visitorID. Luckily we use a third party service which sends an API call every time a form value changes which uses it's own ID. These IDs are consistent between the first half of the form, and the remainder of the form, and the only way I can save the leads from the lost session issues.

I should also note that this works fine 99% of the time.

**EDIT:**
I've modified my code to explicitly store my lead object in TempData and used the TempData.Keep() method to persist the object between subsequent requests. I've only deployed this behavior to 1 of my 3 sites but so far so good.

I had also tried storing my lead objects in Session directly in the controller action i.e.,

```
Session.Add("lead", this._Lead);
```

which uses HTTPSessionStateBase, attempting to circumvent the wrapper class, instead of HttpContext.Current.Session which uses HTTPSessionState. This modification made no difference on the issue, as expected.

**EDIT #2:**
Checking my email this morning I noticed two Session errors despite saving my lead model in TempData. Something is causing session to clear, most likely an app pool recycle of some sort, but I haven't been able to figure it out yet. I'm probably going to start storing session in SQL Server...

SessionStore.cs code by request:

```
public static class SessionStore
{
    private static HttpSessionState Session
    {
        get { return HttpContext.Current.Session; }
    }

    public static T Get<T>(object name, T defaultValue)
    {
        var key = name.ToString();
        return SessionStore.Session.ContainsKey(key) ? (T)Session[key] : defaultValue;
    }

    public static void Set(object name, object value)
    {
        SessionStore.Session.Add(name.ToString(), value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you include the SessionStore code as well?

Comment: This whole process seems highly brittle and error prone.  What happens if you have a user with two tabs open on the same page, and they refresh them at the same time, or submit them at the same time?  It looks like they would overwrite each others leads.  That's the problem with using Session, it's shred between all tabs the user may have open.  Why don't you just store the lead in the database?

Comment: These sites are integrated with lead management/call center software/iframes (although this isn't an iframe specific issue). Each representative should only have one instance of our site open at a time and submit one at a time, but if they were to have multiple tabs open, begin filling out one form by submitting the first page, opening another tab, submit another first page, go back to first tab and submit, the first lead would go through. The second tab, if attempted to submit, would redirect to the first form page and they'd have to start over. It's not an issue but i see what you're saying.

Comment: I've also tried to specifically reproduce this error by having multiple tabs open, like you mention, but everything works as expected. If I begin filling a form and clear cache/cookies via the browser and attempt to submit the form's second page, this will reproduce the error. But the representatives aren't doing this. Today, this site got ~2600 unique visitors, and resulted in ~180 submit page submissions. Not sure how many page1 form submissions there were. Out of that, there were 3 session errors, which is lower than average.

Comment: Changing the sessionState mode to SQLServer has had no affect and I continue to receive session errors at random. A very small portion of session error leads actually make it into our database though.

Comment: Well, one way to figure out how this might be happening (if you can recreate it in the debugger) is to not use Session but rather use the HttpContext.Current.Cache and you can then setup a notification when a cache entry is removed (ie replaced with another).  You can then set a breakpoint or log it.  More info here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7kxdx246(v=vs.85).aspx